# Finding words that contain two "g"s (not necessarily adjacent) in a corpus

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find all words in a corpus that contain two g's (not necessarily adjacent). Would I need a regex for this? Here's what I came up with using NLTK, but when I print the length, it's giving me a word count much higher than expected.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

allwords = gutenberg.words()
g_words = []
for word in allwords:
        if 'g' in word and 'g' in word:
            g_words.append(word)
            
print(len(g_words))
```

Also, how to make the count case-insensitive?

Comment: you should've done like `word.count('g') == 2` for the condition in the if statement

Comment: `nltk` knows quite a bit about filtering tokens with regular expressions. Maybe a stint with the documentation would be a good idea.

Comment: Do you want *exactly* two g's or *at least* two g's?

Comment: It has to be exactly two, so I guess "== 2" is correct here(?)

Answer (score 4):

```
'g' in word and 'g' in word
```

is wrong: if the first test is true then so is the second. Use:

```
word.count('g') == 2
```

To make the search case-insensitive:

```
g_words = [word for word in allwords if word.lower().count('g') == 2]
```